# France - Do I need a transit visa?

Tags: transit-visas, air-france

Travelling to India from Chicago via Paris (Charles de Gaulle Airport). I have a valid US visa, and Indian Passport(valid & expired).

Do I really need transit visa?

Looked up online and found this, "https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/france-visa/airport-transit-visa/"

Foreigners who DO NOT NEED an Airport Transit French Visa, regardless their nationality are the following cases:

### holders of the valid US visa.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, you are not required to have a transit visa if you hold a valid US visa.